# Proof of double integration.

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

In the book "A Second Course in Calculus" by Serge Lang, there is a chapter on multiple integrals. The book does not give a justification as to why $$\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to  0,\Delta y\to 0}\sum{f(x,y)\Delta x\Delta y}=\lim\limits_{\Delta y\to 0}\sum\{\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to  0}\sum{f(x,y)\Delta x\}\Delta y}$$

Also, why $$\lim\limits_{\Delta y\to 0}\sum\{\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to  0}\sum{f(x,y)\Delta x\}\Delta y}=\lim\limits_{\Delta x\to 0}\sum\{\lim\limits_{\Delta y\to  0}\sum{f(x,y)\Delta y\}\Delta x}$$

In other words, why  $$\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=\int\left(\int f(x,y)dx\right)dy=\int\left(\int f(x,y)dy\right)dx$$

The book says that the explanation is too advanced for the intended audience. I tried searching online, but couldn't find any relevant articles.

Could you please point me towards the argument?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The theorem of fubini could help.

Comment: As @Peter says. This is called the Fubini theorem in integration theory. However, this is usually proved in the setting of a more advanced integral – the Lebesgue integral. I expect it has been written up in the setting of the Riemann integral somewhere, but I don't know of a source myself.

Comment: I am not familiar with measure theory as of now. So yes, the Reimann integral version would be more helpful. Thanks

Comment: if f(x,y) is continous in the range a<=x<=b and c<=y<=d, then the fubini theorem works for the integral $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d} f(x,y) dy dx$

Comment: problems can occur, if the limits are not finite, or if f(x,y) has poles.